# String is non-numeric Exception in crystal report

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

There is an exception in crystal report for "String is non-numeric".How can i fix it? I have written code to check for null-

```
If IsNull({GL_PayableStatement.RemainingBalance}) OR {GL_PayableStatement.RemainingBalance}="" OR {GL_PayableStatement.RemainingBalance}="0"
then
0
ELse
ToNumber( {GL_PayableStatement.RemainingBalance})
```

[image]

But still no fix!
Please help me.

Comment: what is the datatype of `{GL_PayableStatement.RemainingBalance}`

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is `{GL_PayableStatement.RemainingBalance}` contains some non numeric values hence the best option would be convert the result to stirng.

```
If IsNull({GL_PayableStatement.RemainingBalance}) OR {GL_PayableStatement.RemainingBalance}="" OR {GL_PayableStatement.RemainingBalance}="0"
then
ToText(0)
ELse
{GL_PayableStatement.RemainingBalance}
```